# Basic tags in html clarification

Tags: html

This is basic. If I use a framework, such as Bootstrap, docs say use this tag `<nav` for a navigator(for example), but most people use instead `<div` :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</div>
```

I know that `div` is some kind of container for other views, but how can you simply change the tag `<nav` from the docs, to be `<div` ? if you can, why one need it at all ?

Comment: For me, they just tell you to use [**semantic elements**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) as much as possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why to use HTML5 semantic tag instead of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272019/why-to-use-html5-semantic-tag-instead-of-div)

Comment: possible only. Maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<nav>` acts exactly like `<div>`. Same goes for `article`, `section`, etc...

It only has a semantic meaning, it can make your code more readable and the browser will render it the same.

**BUT** it may affect in different way - some search engines tries to read your page and extract relevant data from your page, organizing your code and using the correct semantic elements might help you get a higher rank or a better summery of your page.

Also, if you use a framework, it might style specific elements differently.

Consider this code, if you'll change all the tags to div, the styling won't be the same:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

article{
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</nav>
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Article title</h1>
    <p>article content here</p>
    <p>article content here</p>
    <p>article content here</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Here's the same CSS code with the same HTML structure but all the tags are divs

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

article{
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Article title</h1>
    <p>article content here</p>
    <p>article content here</p>
    <p>article content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but you didn't assign classes to the `<div>` elements. If you changed the CSS nav style to `.nav` and listed `<div class="nav">` it would display the same as `<nav>`.

Comment: You're correct, it will work, but when you're using a framework or a mini framework at work, for example, you'll have to make sure it has this classes, otherwise altering thousands of lines in the CSS code and usually multiple files, it's not always possible

Comment: I cannot imagine having thousands of lines of CSS, but then I code separate CSS pages for the different sections of my site(s).

Answer (score 3):

**I hope this will help you to understand what are you want to know about.**

The `nav` tag is a tag of HTML5, it is possible to use `div` tag instead of `nav` tag & it's not compulsory to use nav tag for navigation. It just clarify that `nav` tag is use for navigation, header is for header area and footer is for footer area. They all are HTML5 basic tags which clarify by their names that for which area is use for, all HMTL5 tags are also known as block tags as same like div tag. So does't matter your are using `div` tag instead of `nav` tag it will work same.

And talking about loosing their styles, it will only loose their style if the class is define with the tag name and without space like `nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg`, but in bootstrap it defines without tag name `.navbar.navbar-expand-lg`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap template in your website.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)