# Creating an array of image objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of image objects, but struggling. Each object will hold an image and a caption for the image.

The following code works fine when I paste it into Firebug for checking:

**Example 1**

```
var imageArray = new Array();

imageArray[0] = new Image();
console.log(imageArray[0]);  //result is <img>

imageArray[0].src = "my-image-01.png";
console.log(imageArray[0]); // result is <img src="my-image-01.png"/>

imageArray[0] = {imageCaption: "A caption for the image"};  //an object
console.log(imageArray[0].imageCaption) //result is: A caption for the image

imageArray[1] = new Image()
```

... etc

However, I thought the following would make more sense, but it keeps throwing an error and I can't understand why.

**Example 2**

```
var imageArray = new Array();

imageArray[0]= {
    image01: new Image(),
    image01.src: "my-image-01.png",  //"SyntaxError: missing : after property id"
    imageCaption: "An image caption"
    };

imageArray[1] = {
    image02: new Image().
    image02.src: "my-image-02.png",
    imageCaption: "Another image caption"
    }
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with the code above? Is the first example I posted, the approach I should use? Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to use a sort of [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to the images array.

Try something like this

```
// Image factory
var createImage = function(src, title) {
  var img   = new Image();
  img.src   = src;
  img.alt   = title;
  img.title = title;
  return img; 
};

// array of images
var images = [];

// push two images to the array
images.push(createImage("foo.jpg", "foo title"));
images.push(createImage("bar.jpg", "bar title"));

// output
console.log(images);
```

Output

```
[
  <img src=​"foo.jpg" title=​"foo title" alt="foo title">​, 
  <img src=​"bar.jpg" title=​"bar title" alt="bar title">​
]
```

Comment: This works great - many thanks. I'm not familiar with the factory method, so time for me to brush up on some extra reading :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you have

```
var imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[0] = new Image(); // an image object
imageArray[0].src = "my-image-01.png"; // src set in image object

// Here you are completely destroying the image object and creating a new object
imageArray[0] = { imageCaption: "A caption for the image" };  //an object
console.log(imageArray[0]); // Object {imageCaption: "A caption for the image"}
```

In your second example, you have

```
imageArray[0]= {
    image01: new Image(),
    image01.src: "my-image-01.png",  // <-- this is wrong
    imageCaption: "An image caption"
};
```

Here `image01` is only a key/string not an `object` and `image01.src` is making the error because of the `.` in it, a key name can contain `_` and space (if quoted, i.r. `'key one'`). So, you can use it this way, but I think you can remove the `image01 : new Image()` and just can create new images when you use this objec, [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/LLmqb/142/), anyways.

```
var imageArray = [];
imageArray[0] = {
    image01 : new Image(),
    src : "my-image-01.png",
    imageCaption : "Image caption for image-01"
};
imageArray[1] = {
    image01 : new Image(),
    src : "my-image-02.png",
    imageCaption : "Image caption for image-02"
};

for(x = 0; x < imageArray.length; x++) {
    console.log(imageArray[x].src);
}
```

So, `console.log(imageArray[0].src);` will output `my-image-01.png`. If you want to use a `caption` in the image object itself then there is no `caption` attribute for image object, instead you can use `data-caption` or `alt` to use later somehow, but using [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) you can use a caption like this

```
<figure>
    <img src="picture.jpg" alt="An awesome picture">
    <figcaption>Caption for the awesome picture</figcaption>
</figure>
```

An [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/LLmqb/141/). Also, as an alternative, you may look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129273/741747) with example.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed explanation and for pointing out where the errors are occurring. It all makes much more sense now. I have three excellent solutions, just need to pick one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the first one. Change the third line

```
imageArray[0] = new Image();
imageArray[0].src = "my-image-01.png";
imageArray[0].imageCaption = "A caption for the image";
```

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't realise I could append .imageCaption to the array name to make it work. It seems so simple now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- there's a . instead of a , at image02 in imageArray[1]
- you cannot use a `.` as attribute name of  an object

So the code should look something like this:

```
imageArray[0]= {
    image: new Image(),
    src: "my-image-01.png",  //"SyntaxError: missing : after property id"
    caption: "An image caption"
};

imageArray[1] = {
    image: new Image().
    src: "my-image-02.png",
    caption: "Another image caption"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! The code above works great. Everyone's given such great answers, I feel I'm spoilt for choice!

Comment: @ChestnutTree  If this is the most helpful answer in your opinion, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark under the vote counter.

Answer (score -1):

**First**: System.Array class is abstract, you can't istanziate it. [You can use ArrayList from collections]

**Second**: to assign a value within object initializzation you must use "=" and not ":"
followed by "," like this: new Image { src = "my-image-01.png", imageCaption = "An image caption" }

your code:

var imageList = new ArrayList();

```
        imageList.Add(new Image { src = "my-image-01.png", imageCaption = "An image caption" });
        imageList.Add(new Image { src = "my-image-02.png", imageCaption = "Another image caption" });
```

Comment: This question is for JavaScript.

Comment: I'll probably go with one of the other solutions, but the response is still appreciated.