# How to change image src in a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

I am using videojs to build a website to play videos and insert some images to the page at certain time point of the video being played. I used the code below to get the current time and insert an image in "imageContext" div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
    var added = false;
    var ShowAds=function(){
        var time = myPlayer.currentTime;
        var img = document.createElement('IMG');
        div = document.getElementById("imageContext");
        div.style.width = '100px';
        div.style.height = '100px';
        div.style.display = 'inline-block';

        if(time > 30 && time <= 40 && !added){
            //img.onload = function(){
            div.appendChild(img);
            added = true;

            img.setAttribute("src",'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shqc.jpg');

            img.style.width = '100%';
            img.style.height = 'auto';
        }else if(time > 70){
            //change to another image in the same position
        }

    }
    myPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate',ShowAds,false);
</script>
```

What if I want to show another image on the page when the time changes to, say, the 90th second? Or is there any way to delete the image on the page using javascript? Thanks!

To be clear, I have tried to put

```
img.setAttribute("src",'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yy.jpeg');
```

under else, it doesn't work

Comment: Then just do another `img.src = 'url'` when time is 90

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: Just a style note: It is generally recommended that only constructor functions be named starting with a capital letter.

Comment: What's up with using a path on your filesystem ("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shqc.jpg") as your image src?  Are you not serving this off of a local server?

Comment: no, another img.src = 'url' doesn't work

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ yes, it's duplicated, I didn't notice this one, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Demonedge no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set an `id` to the `img` element when you create it, (In case if you have multiple `img` tags inside the document)

```
img.setAttribute('id', 'myImg');
```

Then, check whether time equals `90` the same way you check whether it is between `30` and `40` and change the `src` of it like below.

```
if(time == 90 ){
    document.getElementById("myImg").src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/your_image.jpg";
}
```

> In case if you want to delete the `img` element, since it has a parent
>   (`imageContext`), you can do this,
>
> ```
> var el = document.getElementById('myImg');
> el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
> ```

Comment: That is great! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
document.getElementById("image").src="/PATH/To/Image/file.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is this:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = //whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating and array of images locations.

```
var imageArray = new Array();

imageArray[0]= {
 image01: new Image(),
 image01.src: "my-image-01.png",
 imageCaption: "An image caption"
};
```

Then at the next interval just set the image attribute to the src of a picture in the array or just append the whole image.

```
if(time > 90 && time <= 100 && !added){
        div.appendChild(img);
        added = true;

        img.setAttribute("src",imageArray[0].src);

        img.style.width = '100%';
        img.style.height = 'auto';
```

Hope that helps. 
I used a little help from this other stack overflow question and answer: 
[Creating an array of image objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351408/creating-an-array-of-image-objects)