# Inline images with captions centered under each?

Tags: html, css

How would I display multiple images on the same line, and put captions centered under each one using HTML/CSS?

Here's what I currently have:

HTML:

```
<div class="iconbox">
       <div id="tut-icon"><p><img src="images/tuticon.png" alt="Written Tutorials" />Some text</p></div>
       <div id="vid-icon"><p><img src="images/vidicon.png" alt="Video Tutorials" />Some text</p></div>
       <div id="add-icon"><p><img src="images/addtuticon.png" alt="Add Tutorials" />Some text</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.iconbox {
height: 128px;
padding: 20px;
display: inline;
}

#tut-icon, #vid-icon, #add-icon {
text-align: center;
width: 128px;
}

#tut-icon img, #vid-icon img, #add-icon img {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/swiftsly/24m7L/

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10128950/1741542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

HTML:

```
<div class="iconbox">
    <div id="tut-icon">
        <img src="images/tuticon.png" alt="Written Tutorials" />
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="vid-icon">
        <img src="images/vidicon.png" alt="Video Tutorials" />
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="add-icon">
        <img src="images/addtuticon.png" alt="Add Tutorials" />
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.iconbox {
    height: 128px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.iconbox > div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 128px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.iconbox p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24m7L/3/)

or

```
.iconbox {
    height: 128px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.iconbox > div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 128px;
    float: left;
}
.iconbox p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24m7L/5/)

(after the float you would then probably want to apply a [**clearfix**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix))

Comment: Thanks, works well.  Just moved the "text-align: center;" tag to the ".iconbox p" section to center the text.

Comment: to have the image and the text centered you should leave the `text-align` property on the `div` elements (it then anyway gets inherited).

Answer (score 1):

Edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/24m7L/1/

Try and use classes if you find yourself copying ids everywhere.

This uses `inline-block` which is not working correctly IE <= 7 (http://caniuse.com/inline-block)