# Description/title below unopened fancybox images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox gallery, I want to add a name below each image as description before it is opened. For some reason I can't figure this out.
My code:

```
 <a class="fancybox" href="images/fb1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery"               title="Automated Batching System"><img src="images/fb1_t.jpg" alt="Automated Batching System" class="imgrnd"  /></a>
```

If I try to add a paragraph or something below each image it forces the next image to a new line.

Your help would be welcome, thanks

Comment: Code is above. I have a gallery of 15 images, I want to add a description below each image that the visitor sees before he clicks on the image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please elaborate with relevant code sample and, if possible, a jsfiddle to show what exactly it is that you want.

Edit: Please see this link as it gives a simple solution [How to write a caption under an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128950/how-to-write-a-caption-under-an-image)

In your case, just try to enclose each image inside a div, and set the 'float' css property to 'left'

```
<div>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/fb1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Automated Batching System">
<figure>
<img src="images/fb1_t.jpg" alt="Automated Batching System" class="imgrnd"/>   
<figcaption>Some title</figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
</div>

<div>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/fb1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Automated Batching System">

<figure>
<img src="images/fb1_t.jpg" alt="Automated Batching System" class="imgrnd"  />
<figcaption>some Title</figcaption>
</figure></a>
</div>
```

And your CSS property:

```
div
{
float:left;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The answer is supposed to be an answer, What you gave is a comment, so please try to post them in comments.

Comment: My bad, I was trying to post a comment, but by mistake posted it as answer.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks, but suddenly big spaces between images, css stayed the same.

Comment: You can try to modify the padding and margin for the various tags involved, especially the figure tag, such as: figure
{
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}

Comment: You're welcome :) Please mark this as answer if this satisfies your query.