# Centering properties with html

Tags: html, css

I have a picture and Text under, How could I center both and make them right under eachother (equal in width). Also to center them in the middle of the web page I tried `"div: wrapper"` but it didnt work, any ideas?

```
 <?php 

 require "header.php";
 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

 <img src="Page.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" width="1200" height="500">

 <div style='background-color:gray; color:white;align:center; width:1500; height:500;  position: absolute;'>

 <h3 style= 'font-weight:bold'>TEXT HERE.<br>

TEXT HERE

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need css for that

Comment: I'm not seeing much of an attempt here. `align` is not a valid CSS property. I foresee this question getting closed due to it's poor quality and the fact that this question has been asked many times before.

Comment: Try using `figure` and `figurecaption` per the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128950/how-to-write-a-caption-under-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `figure` and `figcaption`, and using `margin:auto` in block level elements will make center in your page

---

Note you have a few errors on your code:

- `width/height` are unit-less
- `align`in CSS is a property that doesn't exist, you were looking for `text-align`
- and don't use inline styles

---

```css
body,
figure,
h3  {
  margin: 0
}
figcaption {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center
}
figcaption,
img {
  width: 500px;
  /*changed for demo*/
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block
}
img {
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="//placehold.it/1200x500" alt="HTML5 Icon">
</figure>
<figcaption>
  <h3><strong>TEXT HERE.</strong><br /></h3>
  TEXT HERE
</figcaption>
```

Comment: One note (I know you know this @dippas), when centering with auto margins a width needs to also be set in order for auto margins to work, i.e. `div { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }`. Which was done in the answer above but not so much in the comment about auto margins. I'm a bit of a stickler for `width + auto margins = centering`.